# Where are sound themes located?

Tags: sound, themes

Where are sound themes located?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok seems like I need to answer this :p. usually sound files are located in `/usr/share/sounds`. You can check there.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers state, sound themes are directories located in `/usr/share/sounds/`

However, it is important, that a directory which has to be a sound theme MUST contain a file named `index.theme`, with some basic information about the theme (see /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/index.theme for example).